# I'm building a react native application with complex stack and tab navigation and i'm having trouble in stack navigation

Tags: react-native, mobile-application, react-navigation-v5, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I have homescreen where I have three buttons: Receive, Deliver ,Return. In the bottom tab navigation I have same buttons. Now inside the deliver screen i have also have a return button where the user can click on it if the customer wants to return the shipment. My issue is when I click on deliver button from home screen then click on return button that is inside deliver screen I get " ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"NestedReturn"} was not handled by any navigator." whereas if i click from bottom navigation same scenario. it works perfectly fine. Note: i have two types of users each has it's own navigation.
This is My APP navigation

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        {authState?.token ? (
          <>
            {authState.userType === UserType.shipper ? (
              <>
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                      <MaterialIcons name="home" size={size} color={color} />
                    ),
                    headerShown: false,
                  }}
                >
                  {() => (
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="HomeScreen"
                        component={HomeScreen}
                        options={({ route }) => ({
                          headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
                        })}
                      />

                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedReceive"
                        options={{ title: "Receive" }}
                        component={ReceiveScreen}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedDeliver"
                        options={{ title: "Deliver" }}
                        component={DeliverScreen}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedReturn"
                        options={{ title: "Return" }}
                        component={ReturnScreen}
                      />

                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="Settings"
                        component={SettingsScreen}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />

                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="BarCodeScanner"
                        component={BarCodeScanner}
                        options={({ route }) => ({
                          title: route.params.fromScreen,
                        })}
                      />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                  )}
                </Tab.Screen>
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Receive"
                  initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedReceive" }}
                  listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: (event) => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      navigation.dispatch(
                        CommonActions.navigate({
                          name: "BarCodeScanner",
                          params: {
                            fromScreen: "NestedReceive",
                          },
                        })
                      );
                    },
                  })}
                  options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        name="email-receive-outline"
                        size={size}
                        color={color}
                      />
                    ),
                    headerShown: false,
                    headerTitle: "receive",
                  }}
                >
                  {() => (
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                      <Stack.Screen
                        initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedReceive" }}
                        name="BarCodeScanner"
                        component={BarCodeScanner}
                        options={{ title: "Receive" }}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedReceive"
                        options={{ title: "Receive" }}
                        component={ReceiveScreen}
                      />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                  )}
                </Tab.Screen>

                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Deliver"
                  initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedDeliver" }}
                  listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: (event) => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      navigation.dispatch(
                        CommonActions.navigate({
                          name: "BarCodeScanner",
                          params: {
                            fromScreen: "NestedDeliver",
                          },
                        })
                      );
                    },
                  })}
                  options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        name="truck-delivery-outline"
                        size={size}
                        color={color}
                      />
                    ),
                    headerShown: false,
                    headerTitle: "Deliver",
                  }}
                >
                  {() => (
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                      <Stack.Screen
                        initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedDeliver" }}
                        name="BarCodeScanner"
                        component={BarCodeScanner}
                        options={{ title: "Deliver" }}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedDeliver"
                        options={{ title: "Deliver" }}
                        component={DeliverScreen}
                      />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                  )}
                </Tab.Screen>

                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Return"
                  initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedReturn" }}
                  listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                    tabPress: (event) => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      navigation.dispatch(
                        CommonActions.navigate({
                          name: "BarCodeScanner",
                          params: {
                            fromScreen: "NestedReturn",
                          },
                        })
                      );
                    },
                  })}
                  options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                      <Octicons
                        name="package-dependencies"
                        size={size}
                        color={color}
                      />
                    ),
                    headerShown: false,
                    headerTitle: "Return",
                  }}
                >
                  {() => (
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                      <Stack.Screen
                        initialParams={{ fromScreen: "NestedReturn" }}
                        name="BarCodeScanner"
                        component={BarCodeScanner}
                        options={{ title: "Return" }}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="NestedReturn"
                        component={ReturnScreen}
                        options={{ title: "Return" }}
                      />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                  )}
                </Tab.Screen>
              </>
```

and here how i handle the return button in deliver component

```
  const handleReturn = () => {
    navigation.navigate("NestedReturn");
  };
```